# How to control inner and outer edge of curve modifier separately?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, transforms, edges, procedural

I am working on a project where I need to create circular roof where the inner edge is always in the same position (has always the same radius), but the outer edge can be adjusted (adjustable radius independent of inner edge). And all this has to be somewhat procedural (cannot lose resolution over size - similar to array over curve, where bigger the radius the more instances spawn).

Visual concept:
[image]

Comment: Is it flat or conical?

Comment: I want it rather conical - it's supposed to be stadium roof

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it without the curve modifier, with the screw modifier and a displace modifier :

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem, would've never guessed it on my own. I plan to use array + curve instead of screw modifier, still works.

Comment: @Bogu Yes it works too, and array + curve gives you more control if you want to add details every now and then

Comment: Nice. But now I'm going to have to pay a visit to my optician. :D

Comment: @RobinBetts The quality is better if you click the gif to open in a new tab ! Damn the 2 Mb limit